# jQuery and div scrollLeft when a label has been clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to scroll a div left/right when a label is clicked. Anyway, my code does not work at all. It seems to me that it does not know when a label has been clicked. On the other hand, it seems to me that the code is not able to scroll the div as it should be. So, maybe I will find some help here.

```
<div id="main" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto">
  <div id="sub" style="overflow: hidden; width: 10000em; margin-left: -5000em; position: relative; left: 50%; text-align: center">
    <div id="navi1"><span><label for="go">Go</label></span></div>

    <input name="go" type="radio" id="go" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
$('label').click(function() {
  var p = $( "div#navi1" );
  var position = p.position();
  // $('#main').scrollLeft(position.left);
  $('#main').scrollLeft(10000);
});
```

Comment: Hi @Xms position.left has 0 value. when I did alert got left: 0 and right :0  have a look this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/UserIsMonica/qmwqqap4/

Comment: @Lioness Thanks Lioness, I modified the opening message. Now you can see the problem even better.

Comment: What result are you expecting?  I tested with your recent update and it works how I expected

Comment: And what browser are you testing in?

Comment: @KScandrett Mozilla Firefor 51.0.1. I expect the scrollbar to move to right. It seems to me that the maximum width is 160000. I would like to know how I can scroll the scrollbar to its maximum value, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems. First you want to use [Offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) rather than [Position](https://api.jquery.com/position/) because `div.navi1` is at the left most position (so 0,0) relative to its parent `div.sub`.

Then you have a quirk of jQuery. It won't allow the scroll whilst still within this `click()` function.  So the way to remedy that is to wrap in a `timeout`:

```
<div id="main" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto">
  <div id="sub" style="overflow: hidden; width: 10000em; margin-left: -5000em; position: relative; left: 50%; text-align: center">
    <div style="display: inline-block" id="navi2"><span><label for="go2">Go2 </label></span></div>
    <div style="display: inline-block" id="navi1"><span><label for="go">Go</label></span></div>
    <input name="go2" type="radio" id="go2" />
    <input name="go" type="radio" id="go" />
  </div>
</div>
<moveToLeft>Click me to position Go to the Left</moveToLeft>

<script>
$('label').click(function() {
   var p = $("div#navi1");
   var offset = p.offset();

   // wont work: $('main').scrollLeft(-offset.left);
   setTimeout(function() {
      $('#main').scrollLeft(-offset.left);
   }, 0);
});

$('moveToLeft').click(function() {    
   var curScrollLeft = $('#main').scrollLeft();
   var scrollOffset = $('#navi1').offset().left + curScrollLeft - 10; // a fiddle factor

   // timeout not needed if element is outside of scroll area.  Only in the case above.
   //setTimeout(function() {
      $('#main').scrollLeft(scrollOffset);
   //}, 0);
});
</script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yzh3ovet/15/

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you also tell me how to scroll to the left position of #navi1?

Comment: There is still a problem if I add more divs. For example, like this: `<div style="display:inline-block" id="navi1"><span><label for="go">Go</label></span></div><div style="display:inline-block" id="navi2"><span><label for="go2">Go2</label></span></div>`

Comment: Please take a look: [https://jsfiddle.net/yzh3ovet/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/yzh3ovet/6/)

Comment: When I click "Click me to position Go to the Left", Go2 will be positioned to the left instead of Go.

Comment: I spent some time testing this properly and found a bug or two. Here is the corrected version: https://jsfiddle.net/yzh3ovet/15/.  I've updated my answer with this.  Also note that you don't need the div in `$("div#navi")`, it will be slower than just finding by Id alone: `$("#navi")`.